# The OP starts a bounty, but is not around even to review comments. Why bother with bounties if such things are going to happen?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I saw a bounty suitable for my skill set.

I went ahead and commented about a few missing pieces of information, but I also tried to replicate the problems OP mentioned. I found the problems mostly relating to version changes in the frameworks he uses and wrote an answer on how to solve them. There were still 2-3 days.

Now, both the bounty duration and the grace period have ended, but the OP has not shown up. Checking the profile info, he was seen last week seemingly when he started the bounty.

The problem here is the time we have spent. Short or long, we are spending our time to find some solution.

Even though I am confident to solve most, if not all, of the problem he is facing, because he was not around and his question was not some popular one to attract people, I gained nothing except personal experience like having new trust issues.

Stack Overflow's bounty system has nothing to prevent this kind of incident.

I feel frustrated now and would like to hear from the community.

PS: It will be hard to accept any answer as this is not something concrete. But I think people will upvote answers which are more valuable than my acceptance.

Comment: It wasn't the OP that started the bounty on the question, if we're talking about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595819/what-can-be-done-about-compiler-synthesis-of-manifest-and-optmanifest-is-deprec/70720546#70720546). And, if we are talking about that user, they have offered bounties 3 times on other people's questions, and never awarded them.

Comment: That's just the reality of how SO  works. Questions, just like answers, are posted by users who have no obligation to stick around or participate past earning reputation. It's unfortunate that you sunk time into someone who went absent, but there's really nothing that can be done about that. If the user is absent, no amount of penalty will make them return.

Comment: Bounty is meant to attract answers and views. Answers are posted not for the sole benefit of the asker, but more importantly for future readers. As long as you were able to find that question and post a useful solution, you can be happy with the outcome, even if you don't receive the bounty.

Comment: The bounty system has [automatic awarding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) precisely to prevent this kind of incident. So it's up to you to create an answer that's good enough to qualify for the automatic award.

Comment: If you can write a good quality answer, <expletive deleted> the bounty. A good answer is its own reward. If you can't write a good answer because the question isn't in an answerable state, <expletive deleted> the bounty. Vote to close and move on.

Comment: @Larnu, it is not, and I don't want a witch hunt thus I don't provide a link. I want opinions, suggestions, or possible solutions to the future of the bounty system.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a flaw in bounties. It is now clear to me it does not deserve the name "bounty" without covering this situation.

- your cat/dog is lost and you have bounty posters all over the town, yet you lock the doors and go on a vacation. Now what?
- a criminal has escaped custody and you start a bounty. Then for whatever reason, you lock the sheriff's department with all personnel out the whole time. What now?

There must be some protection for such things. And for now, I can only think of a "delayed grace period" or something like that.

Currently, the OP cannot shortcut the bounty process if one answer qualifies. They have to wait until the end and have a small window to take action. Many do not understand the outcomes due to this unavoidable long period. So maybe:

- delay the grace period when there are answers, but the OP did not log in and/or visit the post for a while, like for another week or longer.
- when they came, ask the OP if any answer qualifies full or half. Otherwise, ask them specifically click on a checkbox or on a button that he/she will not award any.
- implement a review system, just like other reviews, to see if answers are garbage or not. Experienced eyes can differentiate this.